Undo stack lost after dev container rebuild in VSCode
I've been playing around with dev containers under VSCode (MacOS) and every time I rebuild my dev container the undo stack gets lost, e.g. CMD+Z after editing something in devcontainer.json and rebuilding the container doesn't work.
This hint does not solve my problem:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/tips-and-tricks#_persisting-user-profile
I also tried "remoteUser": "root"
